# Save JTextPane contents(Image ,table) in a file

Tags: java, swing, save, jtextpane

I am trying to make a Text Editor in Java , but I have a few problems.

I can add an image to the with JTextPane with insertIcon(), but when I save it the file is empty ,I am trying to save it as a .doc .
Its the same when I try to change the font , it works in JTextPane but when I save its a default font , not the font/size I had.

This is my saveFile method:

```
      try {
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
        writer.write(text.getText());
        writer.close();
        saved = true;
    } catch (IOException err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :P

EDIT:

I am inserting an image in my JTextPane like this :

```
JFileChooser open = new JFileChooser();
            open.showOpenDialog(null);
            File file = open.getSelectedFile();
            Icon image = new ImageIcon(String.valueOf(file));
           text.insertIcon(image);
```

I am saving the JTextPane to a file using the saveFile method from above.
The image is being added to the JTextPane , everything is fine .But when I open the file the image isnt there.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). 3) Try [`JTextComponent.write(Writer)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#write-java.io.Writer-)

Comment: I tried the method but it wont work.

Comment: Why would you expect an image to be saved when all you're doing is saving text? How would the image be magically written in this situation?

Comment: What point was the edit? Where is that MCVE? Voting to close.

Comment: Yes , I got it , but I tried to use JTextComponent.write(writer) , it still wont work.    @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: @NicuD: and what do writers deal with? Text and only text.

Comment: If you need serious help, follow @AndrewThompson's recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

You could try flushing the writer before you close it. Add the line writer.flush(). This will flush the underlying outputstream. Essentially here the writing to the file begins.

Edit: I tested the code and it writes to a file. Is your problem that the font is not the same as it was before you saved it?

Comment: Yes , and when I insert an image , it wont save to the file.

Comment: The image does not save to the file? You are only writing the text. To save the whole component you would have to do what Andrew suggested. This saves the current state of the component. And not just the text.

Comment: I tried what he said it doesnt work , maybe I didnt do it right ?                   
            text.write(writer);

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the EditorKit. I'll write a more precise answer tomorrow.